# i2cset 16bit register address

Tags: linux, i2c

I have a device communicates through i2c protocol. The registers addresses of the device are 16 bits but Linux i2c-tools supports only 8-bit addresses. But I have found something to handle it.

For example, to read a register at the address on 0x0006, I use the method below: (assuming the `busId` is 0 and the device i2c address is 0x48)

```
i2cset -y 0 0x48 0x00 0x06 # this command sets the register address to 0x0006
i2cget -y 0 0x48 # this command the value 0xBA which is true
```

When I call the `i2cget -y 0 0x48` command again, it returns the value at the next address.

The writing operation works as I expect. But when I try to write into the same register, I fail. I try the below command:

```
i2cset -y 0 0x48 0x00 0x06 0xBA 0x0B i
```

This command doesn't return an error. But when I read the register again, I see the register unchanged.

The device I use is AP0100CS. The register address is writable. I don't know what is wrong with i2cset.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation too, i2cset seems not setting correctly (I'm using a different device)